# Finding Unique Characters in Spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I have created a spreadsheet that shows me what the text is in each language.

I need to create another cell, that will locate any of the special characters that have any added parts on and locate them in a cell for each language.

Is there a way of doing this without scanning through myself and putting them in?

For example:

English - "COUNTER","CHECK"

German - "ZÄHLER", "PRÜFEN"

Special Character - "Ä" , "Ü"

The file is very large and screenshots will be hard to take. I have attempted picking out the individual characters, but this is very time consuming. I have not yet been able to find anything on this subject.

When it comes to excel im not amazing with all the formulas, i can only do a few things.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2S98.png)

Comment: Please can you share a screenshot with how you see the above data taking form in a spreadsheet? Also, include your own honest attempt at solving this issue. What did you research? What did you try? What didn't work and what do you need help with exactly? See [ask] a question with a [mcve]

Comment: read edited post

Comment: Thanks for the update but you could still make a minimal reproducible example in Excel right?

Comment: ye i suppose so

Comment: i have added an image